# Cisco anyconnect vpn client connects to server but there is no connectivity

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, cisco-anyconnect

I can connect to Cisco anyconnect server with no problem but when I ping a destination ip I get:

```
Pinging 172.16.10.153 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.180.52: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

This happens on my windows 10 desktop pc and on my laptop there's no such problem.

After connecting to vpn here's `ipconfig`'s output:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : tamindc.ir
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7d9c:2b50:f191:3748%42
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ca9c:8535:634f:bae1%42
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.180.52
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::

Unknown adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd80::20fa:87fa:5227:ece
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fd80::e1a3:940b:65f1:5f86
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::20fa:87fa:5227:ece%23
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.131
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%23
                                       192.168.0.1
```

Also `route print` gives me:

```
Interface List
 42...00 05 9a 3c 7a 00 ......Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Virtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64
  5...00 ff 0f d3 1b 7d ......Windscribe VPN
 23...f4 6d 04 e7 38 2a ......Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1


IPv4 Route Table

Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.131     35
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
       172.16.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link    192.168.180.52      2
      172.16.8.60  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.180.52      2
   172.16.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.180.52    257
       172.18.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link    192.168.180.52      2
   172.18.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.180.52    257
     172.20.11.11  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.131     36
     172.20.11.12  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.131     36
      188.214.4.9  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.131     36
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.131    291
      192.168.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.131     36
    192.168.0.131  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.131    291
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.131    291
   192.168.180.52  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.180.52    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.131    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.180.52  10000
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.131    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.180.52  10000

Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table

Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 23   4131 ::/0                     fe80::1
 42     36 ::/0                     On-link
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 23   4131 fd80::/64                On-link
 42     36 fd80::/64                On-link
 23    291 fd80::20fa:87fa:5227:ece/128
                                    On-link
 23    291 fd80::e1a3:940b:65f1:5f86/128
                                    On-link
 42    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 23    291 fe80::20fa:87fa:5227:ece/128
                                    On-link
 42    291 fe80::7d9c:2b50:f191:3748/128
                                    On-link
 42    291 fe80::ca9c:8535:634f:bae0/126
                                    On-link
 42    291 fe80::ca9c:8535:634f:bae1/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 23    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 172.16.10.153 is a private network address. That would imply you didn't leave "home" [or your ISP] yet with your connection.

Comment: So what should I do? Anyconnect split tunnel vpn is connected but I cannot access any ip address inside the vpn network. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
The software Netbalancer was causing this issue and disabling it did the trick.

Run `ncpa.cpl`
Right click on `Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Connection` and click properties.
From the items uncheck the `NDIS LightWeight Filter`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).